# categorical distribution in validation set

Tags: machine-learning, validation, multi-class, multilabel

I have a dataset that contains 6877 samples. This is a multiclass multilabel classification which means that we have 9 classes and every sample can belong to one or more of these classes. The total number of classifications is 7359 which means that each sample has in average 1.07 positive predictions.

The distribution between each class looks like this

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |  6   |  7   |  8   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1221 |  722 |  236 |  918 |  616 |  700 | 1857 |  869 |  220 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

How should I pick a validation set from these data? Should I do something like this:

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |  6   |  7   |  8   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |  40  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, independent of multi-label classification, it's better to use [stratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#/Non-exhaustive_cross-validation) folds such that each fold has similar amounts from each class. This is useful in adjusting prior beliefs, which can prevent errors causing from over-representation.

This is harder for multi-label problems, depending on your way of course. But, since your average number of classes per sample is close to $1$, it doesn't seem to be a major problem for you.